# How to strip annotations from Jenkins console logs?

Tags: bash, jenkins, sed

It seems that plugins like AnsiColorer or Timestamper do add a lot of annotations to Jenkins build logs making almost impossible to read by humans.

```
.[8mha:////4OM/YPvKduqdd+uV5C...5pzzohpoGAhpvAUBltjzyAAAA.[0mRunning on master in /home/j/workspace/DFG-storage-cinder-10-pep8-rhos
```

I am looking for a way to clean them from CLI so I can process them.

Comment: What does "_process_" include in detail? Perhaps there's a plugin that can do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

These are embedded chunks of markup (Jenkins ConsoleNotes), added by the AnsiColorer, and "hidden" between the "conceal output" control codes (ANSI escape codes).

You can strip them with a Perl script, like that:

```
 perl -pe 's/\x1b\[8m.*?\x1b\[0m//g;' < log
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `curl` them from:

```
http://<Your Jenkins>/job/<Your job's name>/<Build #>/consoleText
```